# Keyboard shortcuts not working in gnome 3.10

Tags: gnome

I am not a fan of unity so I decided to install gnome 3 on my PC which is running Ubuntu 13.10. But after the installation, I am failing to use some shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the terminal and others for volume. Would someone help me please.

Comment: Are you able to set the shortcuts in Keyboard Settings?

Comment: when i go to keyboard settings, Ctrl+Alt+T is already set for terminal launch. even in dconf editor.

Comment: Add a custom launcher to run `gnome-terminal` instead, then asign it to Ctrl-Alt-T

Comment: thank you so much wilf, but how do i do that? would you explain a bit.

Comment: still not working......

Comment: Is [`gnome-terminal`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-terminal/) (the default terminal) installed, and can you access one - do any shortcuts even work as well?

Comment: You are likely effected by this bug in gnome which is still unresolved: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1217196 You can monitor it until it is resolved.

Answer (score 12):

EDIT: The easier way is reloading gnome shell using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (and then <kbd>r</kbd>)

Older way:

Same is the case for me. Try this

1. `mv .gconf/ .gconf.bak`
2. Logout and Login back.

It worked for me in Ubuntu Gnome 14.10.

Source : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126127/global-keyboard-shortcuts-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: `alt + F2` then command `r` worked fine, thanks.

Comment: note for dumbs like me: type a lowercase "r"

Comment: "Alt+F2 r" no longer works with Wayland.

Answer (score 1):

Open Keyboard Settings, and go to Shortcuts.

Click the `+` to add a new one, enter this, and click 'Apply':
[image: 'Open Terminal' under Name, and 'gnome-terminal' under Command]

Then click 'Disabled', and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to assign that keyboard shortcut.

If it prompts, press 'Reassign':

[image]

Comment: I tried this, the short cut is listed in the list of shortcuts, but the key combination just doesn't activate it. what do I have to do to activate the shortcut? I tried rebooting, log-out and back in... nothing worked

Answer (score 1):

In my case the gnome-settings-daemon process was hang:

```
 0 D alex   3798  3587  0  80   0 - 472136 rpc_wa Apr18 tty2    00:00:17 /usr/libexec/gnome-settings-daemon
```

I just killed it and it reloads automatically. After that everything is working properly.