# Keyboard shortcuts not working in Ubuntu 17.10 with Unity

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 17.10

After I installed Ubuntu 17.10 and installed Unity instead of Gnome keyboard shortcuts stopped working. For example I cannot launch terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or change language using keyboard. It is interesting that simple shortcuts, which involve only one modifier key (like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>) work and the same applies not only to the OS but to the applications as well.

The volume keys and other special keys on the keyboard are not working as well.

Comment: Same problem with 16.04 LTS. This answer helped me: https://askubuntu.com/a/555670/253261

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue too with an update to Ubuntu 17.10 and switch to Unity.

To get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to spawn a `gnome-terminal` I started `ccsm` and went to the "Commands" item in the "General" section entering `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` in "Command line 0" under the "Commands" tab and set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for "Run command 0" under the "Key Bindings" tab. The "Commands" item also needs to be enabled with the tick mark.

In `unity-control-center` under "Keyboard" and "Shortcuts" tab the "Launch terminal" in the "Launchers" section now displays "Disabled".

Comment: Works perfectly : bypassing the unity bug.

Answer (score -3):

I resolved it by reinstalling Ubuntu. It is for sure not the best solution, but I found no other option. It was too annoying for me.

Maybe I damaged some packages while switching from Gnome to Unity and trying to remove Gnome, and that caused issues with shortcuts.

Comment: Maybe this would've helped: https://askubuntu.com/questions/983676/media-keys-no-longer-work-in-ubuntu-17-10

Comment: @o'rety 's linked answer worked for me.

Comment: Not an accepted answer.